# Merge data.frames cause match.names error

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I need to merge many data.frames. Below the sample of the code to reproduce an error. It looks like a bug.

This code works well:

```
df1 <- data.frame(v=1:10, v2=rev(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(vv=1:8, v2=rev(5:12))
df12 <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
df3 <- data.frame(w=2:6, v2=3:7)
df123 <- merge(x=df12, y=df3, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
df4 <- data.frame(x=1:6, v2=1:6)
df1234 <- merge(x=df123, y=df4, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
```

This code produce the error message on the last line: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names. The only change is that nrow(df4) > nrow(df123)

```
df1 <- data.frame(v=1:10, v2=rev(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(vv=1:8, v2=rev(5:12))
df12 <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
df3 <- data.frame(w=2:6, v2=3:7)
df123 <- merge(x=df12, y=df3, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
df4 <- data.frame(x=1:16, v2=1:16)
df1234 <- merge(x=df123, y=df4, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
```

Let's see names of columns of df123

```
names(df123)
[1] "v"    "v2.x" "v2.y" "v2"
```

Then change the last name on arbitrary one

```
names(df123)[4] <- "v3"
```

And now this line of code will work correctly

```
df1234 <- merge(x=df123, y=df4, by.x=1, by.y=1, all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".x", ".y"))
```

Is it bug? I used R 2.13.1 on Win7.
If you need some other information, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Yep, that looks like a genuine bug. This will probably have to be sent to the R listserv. We should try and find the relevant line in merge.data.frame first though.

Comment: I get the same behavior you see for R 2.14.1.  I can also confirm that the error happens with `nrow(df4)` becomes greater than `nrow(df123)`; with `df4 <- data.frame(x=1:10, v2=1:10)` it works and with `df4 <- data.frame(x=1:11, v2=1:11)` it gives the reported error. I imagine the problem is related to, when it works, that `names(df1234)` gives `[1] "v"    "v2.x" "v2.y" "v2.x" "v2.y"`. There are duplicated column names which should not happen for well constructed data frames. The error is being thrown from `ribnd(x,  ya)` (as can be seen from `backtrace()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, I tested it in R 2.14.1 on Windows 7, but I doubt the operating system matters. I recreated a "smaller" test case of the bug here:

```
# Create data.
df1=data.frame(rbind(c(1,10,12,NA)))
df2=data.frame(rbind(c(11,11)))

# Works fine.
merge(df1,df2,by=1,all=T)

#   X1 X2.x X3 X4 X2.y
# 1  1   10 12 NA   NA
# 2 11   NA NA NA   11

# Change the names of the columns.
names(df1)= c('v','v2.x','v2.y','v2')
names(df2)= c('x','v2')

# Same data fails!
merge(df1,df2,by=1,all=T)

# Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
#   names do not match previous names
```

The error occurs in the "merge.data.frame" method, on this line:

```
x <- rbind(x, ya)
```

The problem is that "x" and "ya" don't share the same column names. That problem occurs on this line, just two lines before the previous one:

```
ya <- cbind(ya, x[rep.int(NA_integer_, nyy), nm.x, drop = FALSE])
```

"nm.x" is a set of names c("v2.x","v2.y","v2.x"). and x is a data.frame with two columns with the name 'v2.x'. Interestingly, when you select the columns from this data.frame, it appears to rename one of the columns!

```
names(x)
[1] "v"    "v2.x" "v2.y" "v2.x"
nm.x
[1] "v2.x" "v2.y" "v2.x"
x[,nm.x]
  v2.x v2.y v2.x.1
1   10   12     10
```

I tried to solve this by using the position of the column, instead of the name, but the resulting name is still changed (but the values are now what you want)!

```
x[,c(2,3,4)]
  v v2.x v2.y v2.x.1
1 1   10   12   NA
```

I have [posted this as a bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14786).

Comment: Thank you for you bug report, as I'm relatively newbie in R and could not do such investigation quickly. To solve my initial problem I will replace column names after each merging by their number for example, and in final data.frame replace them with correct names stored in a separate vector (yes, I need duplicated names).

Comment: To close the loop here: A 2012-01-24 entry in the R NEWS file contains "`merge()` is no longer allowed to create a data frame with duplicate column names (which confused PR#14786)." PR#14786 refers to to https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14786 which is the bug report derived from this discussion.