# Keep all data together - one master file

Tags: r

I have a problem with my data. I want to keep my data in one file. There are few csv files which I loaded into R.

```
 > list_of_data
 [1] "Weight.csv" "Lenght.csv" "Age.csv" "Place of Birth.csv"           
 [5] "Sex.csv" "Driver License.csv" "Nationality.csv"
```

In each of the file I have a single information about the patient:

Weight.csv:

```
Name    Weight         
Mark      76
Criss     82
Kate      61
Robb      80
Denis     72
```

Age.csv:

```
Name      Age         
Mark      19
Criss     17
Kate      24
Robb      33
Denis     23
```

I want to move all of the informations to one single matrix. So I created a new matrix:

```
data_mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 5,ncol = 7)
colnames(data_mat) <- c("Name", "Weight", "Lenght", "Age", "Place of Birth", "Sex", "Driver License", "Nationality")
rownames(data_mat) <- c("Mark", "Criss", "Kate", "Robb", "Denis")
```

I don't know how to tell R to find the information about the patient in other csv files and put them together in my new matrix. Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at `merge`?

Comment: You may have a look [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961256/how-to-merge-data-frames-which-are-elements-in-a-list/19961375#19961375).

Comment: Can you not do `data.frame(Weight.csv$Name, Weight.csv$Weight, Age.csv$Age)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to merge all of your individual csv's together.

```
dat.all<-merge(csv1,csv2,by="name")
dat.all<-merge(dat.all,csv3,by="name")
...
```

just do this across all your csv files and then you'll have what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cbind` across all the files, removing the `name` column of all but the first.

```
Weight <- data.frame(Name = c("Mark", "Criss", "Kate"), Weight = c(76, 82, 61))
Age <- data.frame(Name = c("Mark", "Criss", "Kate"), Age = c(19, 17, 24))

cbind(Weight, Age = Age[, "Age"])
##    Name Weight Age
## 1  Mark     76  19
## 2 Criss     82  17
## 3  Kate     61  24
```

Comment: @Thomas, Should we always comment out the result?  I didn't know that.

Comment: Not necessarily. I usually typeset larger results separately from the code, but if it's just a few lines like here, it's easy to just put the result in comments to that it kind of mimics the console output.